# Is it valid to nest <html> inside <html>?

Tags: html, specifications

Is this valid HTML?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head/>
    <body>
        <p>Hello, World</p>
        <html>
            <head/>
            <body>
                <p>Hello, World 2: Revenge of the Pointer</p>
            </body>
        </html>
        <html>
            <head/>
            <body>
                <p>Hello, World 3: GOTO null</p>
            </body>
        </html>
    </body>
</html>
```

According to the [HTML5 specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/semantics.html#the-html-element), the `<html>` element can be used:

> - As the root element of a document.
> - Wherever a subdocument fragment is allowed in a compound document.

It's the second part that I'm confused about. Does this mean that `<html>` is a "document" and any nested `<html>` is a "subdocument fragment"? How can I tell if this is "allowed"?

Comment: In html5 it **is** valid but it also is **bad practice**.  Why would you want to repeat `html`-elements? In your situation, why not use `article` and `section` elements? Just looked a bit further: allthough it is in the specifications, browsers dont seem to like it.

Comment: Doesn't seem to validate and your head tags are incorrect.

Comment: This is not a duplicate. The `<html>` elements are not nested in that question.

Answer (score 3):

As said by Guffa

A compound document is a document in itself and you can't use html to make a sub-document.

But a html may contain a iframe which is a sub-document and has html tag.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

No, that is not valid.

A [compound document](http://www.w3.org/TR/CDR/) has a subdocument fragment declared inside it, which is a complete document in itself. You can't just use another `html` tag to make a compound document.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: It's technically a parse error, but browsers universally ignore parse errors so you can do it if you want. It will be ignored except the attributes will be merged into the root `<html>` element.

See [the HTML parser spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/parsing.html#parsing-main-inbody):

> A start tag whose tag name is "html"
>
> Parse error.
>
> If there is a template element on the stack of open elements, then ignore the token.
>
> Otherwise, for each attribute on the token, check to see if the attribute is already present on the top element of the stack of open elements. If it is not, add the attribute and its corresponding value to that element.

A parse error is not necessarily fatal:

> The error handling for parse errors is well-defined (that's the processing rules described throughout this specification), but user agents, while parsing an HTML document, may abort the parser at the first parse error that they encounter for which they do not wish to apply the rules described in this specification.

In practice no browsers are going to abort for parse errors (as far as I can tell they don't even report them in the dev console) so a nested `<html>` element will just be ignored, except that its attributes will be merged into the root `<html>` element as described.