# Can I put an entire HTML document in a template?

Tags: html

I want to store an entire HTML document to put in an iframe (srcdoc) later.

Am I allowed to put everything in a template including the html, head and body like this?

```html
<template>
  <html>
    <head>
      <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <main>Content</main>
    </body>
  </html>
</template>
```

If not, what's the best way to store an entire document? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, the template tag is not allowed to contain `<html>` tags. per 4.1.1 of the HTML specification:

> Contexts in which [the `<html>`] element can be used:
>
> - As document's document element.
> - Wherever a subdocument fragment is allowed in a compound document.

and from 4.12.3, the `<template>` tag does not provide either of these contexts. For the same reason, you can't use `<head>`, `<body>` or `<title>` tags either. Chrome and Firefox both actively strip out the invalid tags from the `<template>`, preventing you from using it.

The best way of storing HTML for use in iframes is to put the HTML code in a different file in your web server.

However, an acceptable alternative is to store the HTML inside your `<iframe>`, then populating the srcdoc attribute with the content.

```
<iframe id="yourIframe">
  <!-- Everything inside here is interpreted as text, meaning you can even put doctypes  here. This is legal, per 12.2.6.4.7 and 4.8.5 of the HTML specification. -->
  <!doctype html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <main>Content</main>
    </body>
  </html>
</iframe>

...

<script>
...
        const iframe = document.getElementById("yourIframe");
        iframe.srcdoc = iframe.innerHTML;
</script>
```

Comment: That's a great idea, thanks. I assume a compound document is only for including things like SVG?

Comment: Also I tried putting another iframe inside the html but the end tags got confused. Should I escape it like **&lt;/iframe&gt;**?

Comment: Yes, an inline SVG is a good example of a compound document. Other examples are `<iframe>`s, `<embed>`s, any kind of xml content (Mathml, Smil, `<xml>`), etc. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32399301/is-it-valid-to-nest-html-inside-html.

Comment: Yes, this is a downside of trying to inline your iframes this way. If you escape your iframe tags with &lt; you'll have to find a way to unescape it before you insert it into the page. You'll also have to be careful not to unescape any other unrelated &lt;s (which were encoded for a different reason).

Comment: Now that you mentioned it, couldn't we just have a `<svg>` element and then put the entire HTML document in a `<foreignObject>`?

Comment: Never mind that doesn't work, however you can use a `<svg>` element with a CDATA section.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195359/discussion-between-oshah81-and-j-doe).

Comment: Very helpful, thanks! If you need 2 instances of the same remote widget on your page, is `iframe` the way to go about it?